# Comparing strings using std::string::compare, c++

Tags: c++, string, comparison

I have a question:

Let's say there are two `std::string`s and I want to compare them, there is the option of using the `compare()` function of the `string` class but I also noticed that it is possible using simple `< > !=` operators (both of the cases are possible even if I don't include the `<string>` library).
Can someone explain why the `compare()` function exists if a comparison can be made using simple operators?

btw I use Code::Blocks 13.12
here is an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::getline;

int main()
{
    string temp1, temp2;
    cout << "Enter first word: ";
    getline (cin,temp1);
    cout << "Enter second word: ";
    getline (cin,temp2);
    cout << "First word: " << temp1 << endl << "Second word: " << temp2 << endl;
    if (temp1 > temp2)
    {
        cout << "One" << endl;
    }
    if (temp1.compare(temp2) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Two" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's more useful to have a positive, zero, or negative number.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`.compare()` returns an integer, which is a measure of the difference between the two strings.

- A return value of `0` indicates that the two strings compare as equal.
- A positive value means that the compared string is longer, or the first non-matching character is greater.
- A negative value means that the compared string is shorter, or the first non-matching character is lower.

`operator==` simply returns a boolean, indicating whether the strings are equal or not.

If you don't need the extra detail, you may as well just use `==`.

Answer (score 9):

```
string cat = "cat";
string human = "human";

cout << cat.compare(human) << endl;
```

This code will give -1 as a result. This is due to the first non-matching character of the compared string 'h' is lower or appears after 'c' in alphabetical order, even though the compared string, 'human' is longer than 'cat'.

I find the return value described in [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) is more accurate which are-:

> 0  : They compare equal
>
> <0 : Either the value of the first character that does not match is lower in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is shorter.
>
> more than 0 : Either the value of the first character that does not match is greater in the compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is longer.

Moreover, IMO [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)'s description is simpler and so far best describe to my own experience.

> negative value if `*this` appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
>
> zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
>
> positive value if `*this` appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the *question*,

> **”** can someone explain why the `compare()` function exists if a comparison can be made using simple operands?

Relative to `<` and `==`, the `compare` function is conceptually simpler and in practice it *can* be more efficient since it avoids two comparisons per item for ordinary ordering  of items.

---

As an example of simplicity, for small integer values you can write a compare function like this:

```
auto compare( int a, int b ) -> int { return a - b; }
```

which is highly efficient.

Now for a structure

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

auto compare( Foo const& x, Foo const& y )
    -> int
{
    if( int const r = compare( x.a, y.a ) ) { return r; }
    if( int const r = compare( x.b, y.b ) ) { return r; }
    return compare( x.c, y.c );
}
```

Trying to express this lexicographic compare directly in terms of `<` you wind up with horrendous complexity and inefficiency, relatively speaking.

---

With C++11, for the simplicity alone ordinary less-than comparison based lexicographic compare can be very simply implemented in terms of tuple comparison.

Comment: `auto int f(int, int) -> int;` *shudders*. Why the trailing return type?

Comment: @rubenvb: nobody's yet made a case for using two different function declaration syntaxes. i guess the "shuffers" comment and the invalid declaration means you react emotionally to any change here. but i fail to see the utility in using two different syntaxes, when a single one suffices.